# Libraries Conflict for Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, conflicting-libraries

have a weird situation.
I'm using Glassfish server for my Enterprise application. In that application i'm using JSF, Richfaces, Quartz, Jasper Reports, and Commons Email. When I build and deploy application to my dev. computer, dev and test servers, everything works fine. But when I deploy app to Production server with same glassfish I can't run Quartz scheduler. It's giving me that there is some problem with commons-collections. I know there is a conflict somewhere but I can't find where. Can you give me some pointers where to look. By the way I'm using NetBeans 6.5.

Here is the log:

```
[#|2009-02-13T02:00:03.055+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-4;_RequestID=97d21f45-2489-486c-b8d9-68625776c546;|#{SchedulerController.play}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
javax.faces.FacesException: #{SchedulerController.play}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:198)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:390)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:637)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:568)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:813)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:91)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.quartz.JobDetail.<init>(JobDetail.java:85)
    at englearn.elc.controller.SchedulerController.play(SchedulerController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
    ... 44 more
|#]

[#|2009-02-13T02:00:03.055+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-80-4;_RequestID=97d21f45-2489-486c-b8d9-68625776c546;|executePhase(INVOKE_APPLICATION 5,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@77d0f1) threw exception
javax.faces.FacesException: #{SchedulerController.play}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:198)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:390)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:637)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:568)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:813)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{SchedulerController.play}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:91)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.quartz.JobDetail.<init>(JobDetail.java:85)
    at englearn.elc.controller.SchedulerController.play(SchedulerController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
    ... 44 more
|#]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` always indicates that the class file on the runtime classpath is not the same version as the class file that was on the compile-time classpath (if the method had been missing during compilation, the compile would have failed.)

Specifically, the offending method in this case is: `java.util.Set org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(java.util.Set)`

You have a different version of commons-collections in your production environment than you do in your development environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe caused because you are using a commons-collections.jar version which has not that method. To solve this,you need to upload this library (version 3.2.1 is the latest version available) and subsitute all the old commons-collections.jar that you have in your project for the new one (i recomend to make a Search in your Project folder to know all the places in which this library is,because it is surprisingly in lots of places,at least in my case...)

Hope this helps all people with this horrible trouble! It took me a whole day to fix it! Good luck buddies :)

Answer (score 2):

Latest quartz versions do not depend on commons collections library, so try to use newer version. 
In my case switching from quartz 1.6.0 to 1.6.6 fixed the problem.